# How do I get data out of XlsxWriter?

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I have created a `XlsxWriter` object from a `panda.DataFrame`, how would I go about extracting the data from this object?

Ultimately I want to be able extract the data to decide upon the `add_format` to apply.

Comment: Can't you look at data in the dataframe? I don't quite understand the question, sorry.

Comment: I want to dynamically format `XlsxWriter`, based upon the values which I have used to create it.

Comment: You cannot read data out of XlsxWriter. If the data is already in the dataframe then you should use that.